# how to combine a standard method with a doPost method?

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, servlets, post

Basically I have this method:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/addQuestion", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addQuestion(Model model, @RequestParam(value="question", required = true)  String theQuestion , @RequestParam(value="questionId", required = true)  Integer questionId, @RequestParam(value="category", required = true)   String category, @RequestParam(value="correctAnswer", required = true)   String correctAnswer) throws SQLException{
        ViewController viewController = new ViewController();
        viewController.createQuestion(questionId, theQuestion, category, correctAnswer);

        return new ModelAndView("qFour", "question", new Question());
    }
```

But currently I am getting this error "HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL"

So I need a way where I can use the doPost() method but still use this old method as I need a return and I believe doPost() is void.

the ultimate goal is to run the servlet and when data is submitted by the user it appends to the database.

i am trying to call the addQuestion method from this forms action:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="addQuestion" >

   <input type="text" name="questionId" />Enter Id<br>
   <input type="text" name="theQuestion" />Enter Q <br>
   <input type="text" name="category" />Enter Category<br>
   <input type="text" name="correctAnswer" />Enter correct answer<br>
   <input type="submit" value="Next"  >

</form:form>
```

Comment: Can you share your code from where you calling/requesting  this `addQuestion`  ?

Comment: it seems good,it should work.. change this `@RequestMapping(value = "/addQuestion", method = {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})`

and see are you getting some unexpected error as `addQuestion` will support both get and post

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addQuestion", method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView addQuestion(Model model, @RequestParam(value="question", required = true)  String theQuestion , @RequestParam(value="questionId", required = true)  Integer questionId, @RequestParam(value="category", required = true)   String category, @RequestParam(value="correctAnswer", required = true)   String correctAnswer) throws SQLException{
        ViewController viewController = new ViewController();
        viewController.createQuestion(questionId, theQuestion, category, correctAnswer);

        return new ModelAndView("qFour", "question", new Question());
    }
```